# Grid view in yii , checked checkbox return empty

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii

I am using grid view with check boxes in `yii 1.1`, but when I am trying  to get checked values, they are returning array of empty values.

-- I have referred all the answers here

-- I have used `$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("grid-id","selectedIds");` too

Still It's not working for me.

My grid view code is:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'patient-wallet-credit-grid-id',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows'=>100,
    'emptyText'=>"You don't have patients connected yet",
    'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,options){options.data={checkedIds:$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("patient-wallet-credit-grid-id","selectedIds").toString(),
    uncheckedIds:getUncheckeds()};
    return true;}',
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(){
        $("#patient-wallet-credit-grid table").attr("data-tablesaw-mode","columntoggle");
        $("#patient-wallet-credit-grid table").attr("data-tablesaw-minimap","");
        $("#patient-wallet-credit-grid table").attr("data-tablesaw-sortable","");
        $("#patient-wallet-credit-grid table").attr("data-tablesaw-mode-switch","");
        $(document).trigger( "enhance.tablesaw" );
     }',
    'itemsCssClass' =>'tablesaw tablesaw-columntoggle items',
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'check',
            'id' => 'selectedIds',
            'value' => '$data["patient_id"]',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'checked'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState($data["patient_id"])',
        'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(
                'data-tablesaw-priority'=>'1',
                'data-tablesaw-sortable-col'=>'',
                'class'=>'',
                'style'=>"width:10px"
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Name',
            'value'=>'$data["patient_first_name"]',
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(
                'data-tablesaw-priority'=>'1',
                'data-tablesaw-sortable-col'=>'',
                'class'=>'start-xs'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Mobile',
            'value'=>'$data["patient_id"]',
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array(
                'data-tablesaw-priority'=>'1',
                'data-tablesaw-sortable-col'=>'',
                'class'=>'start-xs'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'style'=>'overflow: auto;'
    ),
));
```

I have written the function getUnchecked() in same view ---

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('getUnchecked', "
   function getUncheckeds(){
        var unch = [];
        /*corrected typo: $('[name^=someChec]') => $('[name^=someChecks]') */
        $('[name^=someChecks]').not(':checked,[name$=all]').each(function(){unch.push($(this).val());});
        return unch.toString();
   }
    "
);
```

When I am trying to get values in console by

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("patient-wallet-credit-grid-id","selectedIds");
```

Suppose I am selecting 3 check boxes Then I get Output like ----

```
(3) ["", "", ""]
0: ""
1: ""
2: ""
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```